# Adding a margin in android

Tags: android

I need to add a margin in front of a text view in android but it doesn't work when I use android:layout_marginLeft/Right. Is there another way to do so?

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="7dip"
        android:paddingRight="27dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#10a6a4"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: **add a margin in front of a text view** What it means?

Comment: I think you are talking about `android:paddingLeft="7dip"`. Right?

Comment: I used android:paddingLeft but it doesn't work! I mean I need to addan indent

Comment: Oh thanks so much it works now with the text view but when I apply the same attribute on a button it doesn't! Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `RelativeLayout` ?
margin and padding do not work (as far as I am aware) in `RelativeLayout`s. Try a `LinearLayout` instead, or  if you are using `android:layout_above` and `android:layout_bellow` or these things, put the txtView and the View you're padding it from in one new LinearLayout.
Hope I helped.